# VSCode Source Control (GUI) does not accept user input

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, hook

Part of a work-flow using git post-commit hook, users should be able to provide an answer (input) to the question that a python script in the post-commit hook file asks. If users use the embedded terminal in VSCode, it is working - meaning stdin is provided. However, if users want to commit through the VSCode source-control panel (GUI), then no question pops up and users cannot provide their input (answers). Is there a way to make this possible via VSCode source control? Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem? I am ok with skipping the user interaction if I can somehow determine if the script was called within VS Code GUI. I tried checking the availability of /dev/tty but it is actually available even if run with the GUI...